# How to use clearInterval() and location.reload()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having some trouble getting my app to run properly. It is a trivia app, with a simple countdown timer. My issue is when I want to reset the game (reload the page) when the `setInterval()` is running, it works. But, if the `setInterval()` is stopped by a `clearInterval()` and my Game Over element displays, if I hit Reset, expecting to call `location.reload()`, the page AUTOMATICALLY starts the timer again. This is some kind of looping problem I can't seem to find, but maybe you pros can spot the bug in my code.

I have tried refactoring my code in multiple ways to isolate the bug, but I can't seem to find it.

```
// DOM ELEMENTS ========================================================

const startReset    = document.getElementById("startReset");
const scoreValue    = document.getElementById("score");
const timer         = document.getElementById("timer");
const timerValue    = document.getElementById("timerValue");
const gameOver      = document.getElementById("gameOver");
const correct       = document.getElementById("correct");
const wrong         = document.getElementById("correct");


// GLOBAL GAME VARIABLES ===============================================

let playing = false;
let score;
let action;
let timeRemaining;

// GAME OPERATIONS =====================================================

// Start/Reset Game
startReset.onclick = function() {
    // Reset Game
    if(playing === true) {

        // Reload page
        location.reload();

    } 
        // Start Playing
        else {
            // Change mode from not playing to playing
            playing = true;

            // Take Away Game Over Element
            gameOver.style.visibility = "hidden";

            // Change start button to reset button
            startReset.innerHTML = "Reset Game";

            // Put score back to 0
            score = 0;

            // Update HTML with score
            scoreValue.innerHTML = score;

            // Display timer
            timer.style.display = "block";
            timeRemaining = 60;

            // Start Countdown
            startCountdown();
        }
}

// Start Countdown Function
const startCountdown = () => {
    // Set timer
    action = setInterval(function(){
        // reduce time by 1 sec
        timeRemaining -= 1;
        // update html
        timerValue.innerHTML = timeRemaining;
        // check if time is out
        if(timeRemaining === 0) {
            stopCountdown();
            gameOver.style.visibility = "visible";
            timer.style.display = "none";
            correct.style.display = "none";
            wrong.style.display = "none";
            playing = false;
        }
    }, 100);
};

// Stop Countdown Function
const stopCountdown = () => {
    clearInterval(action);
};
=============================================================
    <body>
        <div id="logoContainer">
            <img src="./images/gotLogo.png">
            </div>

        <div id="container">

            <div id="scoreCounter">
                Score: <span id="score">0</span>
            </div>

            <div id="correct">Correct</div>

            <div id="wrong">Try Again</div>

            <div id="question">
                <p>Click Start to Begin!</p>
            </div>

            <div id="instruction">
                Click on the correct answer!
            </div>

            <div id="choices">

                <div id="choice1" class="choice"></div>
                <div id="choice2" class="choice"></div>
                <div id="choice3" class="choice"></div>
                <div id="choice4" class="choice"></div>

            </div>

            <div id="startReset">
                Start Game
            </div>

            <div id="timer">
                Time Remaining: <span id="timerValue">60</span> sec
            </div>

            <div id="gameOver">
                <p>GAME OVER!</p>
                <p>YOUR SCORE IS: <span id="finalScore">0</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I expect clicking on Reset Game after `Game Over` has appeared to reload the page and force a new click to start the game, however, it reloads the page and AUTOMATICALLY restarts the timer. If I click `Reset Game` while the timer is running, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found. Maybe this will help others.

In my startCountdown() function, in the if statement, I reset playing = false originally, which shortcircuited my conditional logic for the onclick function declared above under Start/Reset game. Taking that away allowed the game to work properly!